# Save sorted value non zero in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 100 columns (items) and 457 rows(products) for `person_1`. So my dataframe 'df_items' for this person is like,

```
     item_1  item_2 ... item_78 ...  item_100
0      0       1          0            1
1      0       1          0            0
2      0       0          0            1
...
456    0       1          0            1
457    0       0          0            1
```

Now, I need the sum on each column, for this I do 
`df_items.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)` and the output is

```
item_1 = 0 
item_2 = 5
...
item_48 = 1
...
item_78 = 0
...
item_100 = 7
```

As you can see, there exist a many columns with sum = 0. These items (with column sum = 0 ) doesn't matter for me.

My question is: **How can I save the name of items (with column sum different of 0) of a sort way in a csv (or excel) file?**

I need to create a csv(or excel) file with rows like

```
person_1  item_100  ... item_5 ... item_48
```

where, the above, is ordered from highest to lowest values and without the 'items with column sum = 0'. For instance, in the above table, in person_1 I might have only 42 columns of the 100 columns.

Any hint will be appreciated, I'm totally new in python. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not delete your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519974/drop-column-by-index-condition) after receiving an answer. It is unfair to the people who have invested time into helping you. Thanks.

Comment: @cs95 I eliminated the question, just one second before that was answered, because I was able to answer myself. Regards

Comment: In that case, you are welcome to write your own answer to the question and earn points for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a np array storing iterms. I use code below to generate the example array:

```py
import numpy as np

items = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
print(items)
```

and the items is like:

```
[6 7 9 8 7 0 0 2 3 6 6 1 0 5 2 0 0 6 6 8 9 9 4 3 9 4 8 6 6 2 2 8 5 2 9 4 1
 2 4 3 5 0 1 7 0 6 8 6 0 7 9 1 2 3 1 7 1 1 2 1 5 5 3 1 3 1 2 2 0 2 5 4 1 3
 7 7 4 8 5 0 6 4 6 8 7 8 6 2 5 3 7 4 8 2 9 5 0 1 3 4]
```

to delete the zero items, you can do:

```py
itemsNoneZero = items[items != 0]
print(itemsNoneZero)
```

you will get:

```
[6 7 9 8 7 2 3 6 6 1 5 2 6 6 8 9 9 4 3 9 4 8 6 6 2 2 8 5 2 9 4 1 2 4 3 5 1
 7 6 8 6 7 9 1 2 3 1 7 1 1 2 1 5 5 3 1 3 1 2 2 2 5 4 1 3 7 7 4 8 5 6 4 6 8
 7 8 6 2 5 3 7 4 8 2 9 5 1 3 4]
```

to sort them:

```py
itemsNoneZero.sort()
print(itemsNoneZero)
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8
 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
```

to store it to a .csv file, you can:

```py
file = open('exp.csv', 'w') # open a csv file to write

# change data to strings, add '\n' means change line
data = [str(d) for d in itemsNoneZero]
data = 'preson ' + ' '.join(data) + '\n'

# write the data to csv file
file.write(data)
```

and you will get the exp.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can convert your Series to a Dataframe and then filter out the rows with zero counts.

Try this:

```
df_sum = df.sum()
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(df_sum, columns=["person_1"])
df_sum[df_sum.person_1 > 0].T
```

Taken a slight variation of your sample data, this prints out to this:

```
            item_1  item_2  item_100
person_1    2       7       8
```

Repeat this procedure with any number of persons and append row wise to a dataframe that you save out then with `pd.to_csv()` or `pd.to_excel()`.